# Rails: has_many association with a table in another database and without foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here is my situation. I have model called Account. An account can have one or more contracts. The problem is that i'm dealing with a legacy application and each account's contracts are stored in a different database.

Example:

Account 1's contract are in account1_db.contracts.
Account 2's contract are in account2_db.contracts.

The database name is a field stored in accounts table.

How can i make rails association work with this?

This is a legacy PHP application and i simply can't change it to store everything in one table. I need to make it work somehow.

I tried this, but it didn't worked:

```
has_many :contracts, :conditions => [lambda{ Contract.set_table_name(self.database + '.contracts'); return '1' }]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't database migration an option?

You're approaching this the wrong way. You want the two systems in your integration to be *loosely* coupled. By trying to get the two associated, you're creating an array of interdependencies that will later come around to backstab you. The approach you are trying creates tight coupling and reduces cohesion.

---

But, to *directly* answer your question, see below. Once again, I don't *recommend* implementing what I say below, but it would technically be a solution.

The first thing is that rails associations work only with foreign key. In fact, *all* database associations work this way. There isn't a ActiveRecord method of association without foreign keys as it defies what it means to associate two objects.

So you're not going to get it done with a has_many association. Instead, I would just manually create a function on your Contract model that simulates a has_many association.

```
class Account
    memoize :contracts

    def contracts
     # Load from other database in here
    end

    def contracts=
    # Push to other database in here
    end
end
```

Comment: Database migration is not an option because other systems use them and they are all crappy PHP apps. As you might imagine, they don't have any kind of tests and rewriting them is out of question.

Comment: Use an API interface / webservices then. It's far from ideal, of course, but it would get the job done.

Comment: Also, i thought about doing an API but i really would like to use the power of Rails and easiness to validate, build nester forms etc. Writing an API would take a long time specially because all validation would have to be written in PHP. Also building nested forms and inserting/updating data won't be that easy.

Comment: This might help: http://www.setfiremedia.com/blog/rails-has-many-through-association-across-databases

But without a foreign key, you're screwed.